# Similar matrices and their arithmetic mean

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Problem:

- Is it possible to find two **different** similar matrices $A$ and $B$
  such that the matrix $C=(A+B)/2$ would be similar to both  $A$,
  $B$ matrices?
- What properties should have  $A$ and $B$ to generate such matrix $C$?

Comment: If $A$ is similar to $B$ then you would only need to show that $C$ is similar to $A$ or $B$, and it will be similar to the other. That is, if $C$ is similar to $A$, then $C$ is similar to $B$ (same is true for reversing $A$ and $B$).

Comment: @Dave Yes, I know.. but the problem is to find this similar matrix $C= (A+B)/2$. I was testing for example orthogonal matrices but for this class of matrices probably there is no solution.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that you weren't trying to do twice the work. I have tried using the definition of similar matrices, but in one attempt the result was that $A=B$. So I am not sure that there is no solution, but I also haven't found one yet.

Comment: @Dave ok, let's try to find it..

Comment: I suspect that there is no nice criteria for this. Intuitively, similarity is about multiplicative property, and arithmetic average is additive one. What I found so far is both existence and nonexistence are possible.

Comment: @i707107 The existence is possible? Do you have some examples?

Comment: $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @i707107 Interesting example. All $A,B,C$ matrices have the same double eigenvalue (in this case equal 1 as in the identity matrix ). Maybe it is criterion ? However are you sure they are similar ? What is transforming matrix $P: A=P^{-1}BP$

Comment: $P=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ works for similarity in i707107's example (i.e. $PA=BP$).

Comment: @Dave Thank you Dave. So it seems that we have a good example - I suppose that matrices of this form give shearing (horizontal) transformations.  Probably all shearing matrices must have the property which enables them to generate similar matrix C. It was 2-dimensional example .. I wonder whether in 3D shearing matrix has also this property...

Comment: @Dave I've  checked some 3-d upper triangle matrices with 1's on the diagonal. They have always 3 eigenvalues = 1 .. maybe they are similar to each other ( could it be proved ?)  which can make them good candidates for searched matrices A,B...

Comment: @i707107 Now I suspect that any upper triangular matrices A,B with the same elements on the diagonal can generate similar matrix C, obviously they have the same eigenvalues, trace, determinant...

Comment: @Widawensen It depends on $A$, $B$. For example, $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ does not work.

Comment: @i707107 here we have a special case. C is identity matrix,,but really it breaks the rule.